# Converting SQL code to DAX within Power Bi

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have written a SQL subquery and I am trying to essentially recreate this within Power BI but it is more complicated than I thought and I am not getting the correct value.

SQL:

```
select sum(x.totalbays)
from
(
select distinct day_id, sum(distinct ranged_bays) as totalbays  from overviewTable
group by day_id
) x
```

`Total in SQL: 15,219,683.76`

DAX:

```
TestMeasure = 
  SUMX (
        SUMMARIZE ( 'Overview Table', 'Overview Table'[day_id], "TotalBays", SUM('Overview Table'[ranged_bays])),
        [TotalBays]
    )
```

`Total using DAX: 87,023,857.19`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might I suggest a nested iterator to handle the `distinct` in your subquery?

```
TestMeasure =
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Overview Table',
        'Overview Table'[day_id],
        "TotalBays",
            SUMX (
                DISTINCT ( 'Overview Table'[ranged_bays] ),
                'Overview Table'[ranged_bays]
            )
    ),
    [TotalBays]
)
```

Edit: Perhaps even simpler, given some extra thought:

```
TestMeasure =
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Overview Table',
        'Overview Table'[day_id],
        'Overview Table'[ranged_bays] 
    ),
    'Overview Table'[ranged_bays]
)
```

Comment: The second one looks promising and avoids nested iterators which can be a performance bottle neck. Have an  upvote.

Comment: Nested iteration was precisely why I didn't want to "let it go" without some extra thought - I think the straight `SUMX` over the summarized table is the way to go - given that I have interpreted the SQL query correctly.